# Unreal Engine Niagara Write to Texture or Data Structure

Tags: textures, unreal-4, particles, unreal

In the Niagara system, is there any way to write to a texture? I want to write the position of each particle into a texture. So the 2d grayscale texture has its intensity as the number of particles in the pixel.

Or, is there any data structure that I can use to store the particle positions? Something like 2d or 3d array?

Comment: "So the 2d grayscale texture has its intensity as the number of particles in the pixel." this sounds like just rendering your particle system over a black background, with additive particles of colour (1, 1, 1), 1px wide. With linear blending that would give you a greyscale texture with grey intensity counting the number of particles at each point. Can you clarify though, why you want this texture? There may be other routes to that end.

Comment: This may actually be a solution. The texture is meant to send intensity data to the particles itself. But I just was expecting a simpler way, something like WriteTextureSample() or Write2dArray()